# Home-printed ad with tear-away strips

Tags: word-choice

Have you seen those home-printed ads, usually pasted on community boards, with cut-up strips at the bottom with the phone number printed on each strip so to allow anyone interested to tear off one of the tabs to phone later? I think they are not common outside the USA.

Is there an idiomatic term to that kind of ads?

I've thought of "tabbed ads" and "tear-away ads" but I've just made that up.

[image]

Comment: General "flyers".

Comment: Tear-away ads:https://www.google.it/search?q=tear-away+ads&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=677&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IAQ5VaWYBs2R7AbJ4oCABw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=tear-away+ads+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always called the bits at the bottom "tear strips". As, apparently, do [others](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/advertising-marketing-ideas-public-bulletin-boards-50156.html).

The whole page is just a flyer, bulletin or ad(vertisement).